# iOS5 iPhone4 InterfaceBuilder suddenly all of my views have transparency. How to fix?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, interface-builder

I have a set of UIViews arranged in layers one over another. I've added another ImageView and added several images to that via `imageView.animationImages` property. A weird thing happened: all of the sudden, all of my views above the image view have transparency, causing a very glitchy feeling.

Is this a bug, or did I toggle some sort of blending property by accident? I've checked, all the views have alpha set to 1, as expected in the IB.

Thank you for your help!

Solution:
The offending line of code was:

```
 self.tabBar.view.alpha = 0.7;
```

I was trying to create a transparent tabbar (my navbar is already transparent).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't a bug. You have to know when you set transparency in a view, all their subview will have transparency too.

So, you create a `superView`and than:

```
[superView addSubview:view1];
[superView addSubview:view2];
```

After this, you set

```
[superView setAlpha:0.0f];
```

Than view1 and view2 will have their `alpha=0.0f`

To solve this, you have to create 2 other views in this way:

```
           / - transparentView
SuperView -               
           \               / - view1
            \ - OtherView -
                           \ - view2
```

Than you have the efect you want.

Comment: Thanks for a quick, great answer, you helped me find the solution!